# I currently have multiple jobs, should I list them all on my resume?

Tags: resume

For a series of unfortunate reasons, I'm in a situation where I have a full-time job, two part-time jobs (5 and 20 hours/week), and also minor self-employment. I've found a new full-time job I'd like to replace my current full-time job with - As my other jobs are flexible, I know they won't impact my ability to do the new job, but I'm afraid it will seem to employers:

1. Like I'm too busy to commit to the full-time position. I'm 100% sure that I will have the time and energy to commit to this job, as my current one is likely more demanding, and I do my current job without any issues.
2. As if I'm lying/making mistakes on my resume. It's pretty rare in the UK to have so many jobs.

These part-time jobs aren't particularly relevant to the job I'm applying for, though my self-employment is. I know normally you shouldn't bother with listing irrelevant/short jobs, but they're all current employments, and I've been in all these jobs for at least a year, now.

**Should I list all my current employments? Even the less relevant ones?**

Comment: How do you manage a 65h/week schedule? Thats 11h/day, plus commute. I now its not really relevant to your question, but it sparked my interest.

Comment: @Polygnome, I would assume he doesn't work all 3 every day. I once worked with a guy who worked at our company full time, then worked as a waiter at a restaurant a few streets away in the evening for a few hours per week night and then another another few hours on the weekend. OP probably doing something similar I imagine.

Comment: Well, a "full time" job implies 37-42h/week. And he said 20+5h for he other jobs. Even is he doesn't do every job every day, its still *on average* 11h/day. thats .... a lot.

Comment: Of course it's a lot, but it's not 11hrs per day. Assuming 65 hours a week, that's a little under 9.5hours a day on average. Like my old coworker, I'd assume he worked full days on the weekend (~16hrs in total) and then ~2hrs in the evenings during the week on top of his full time job.

Comment: @Polygnome the longterm trick I find to working several jobs and I work at least 12 hours a day and often more is to have them in different fields. So I might be various types of engineering in my main job, some development in another, and mowing lawns on weekends etc,.

Comment: It sounds like your self-employment job is so minor, you may not have enough to say about it, or not enough proof: like pay stubs, references, or achievements to be able to talk positively about it. Maybe, you should mention at least one of your other jobs if that's the case. Definitely read the fine print of any contract they offer you. And don't overwork yourself. After a certain point, overworking multiple jobs will create diminishing returns. And the employer that offers you the most money, or the most hours, should be the one that gets your loyalty.

Comment: The linked answer simply does not answer the OPs question.  It only answers how to list concurrent jobs, not whether it would be wise to do so in a given situation.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how it is in the UK, but I know in certain countries it's not uncommon for employment contracts to stipulate something to the effect that you don't have any conflicting interests (this tends to be most common for what we would call "casual" work here, like what you would do at McDonalds). Depending on the potential employer, your guarantee might not be good enough so you'll need to investigate that with them.

That said, my recommendation would be to list the jobs and make sure that it's clear they're part time/casual work and be prepared to explain the situation and how you can be certain they won't conflict with this job. I would not recommend leaving them off because of the above reason, always best to be transparent.